# error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'BaseMenu' to 'BaseMenu *'

Tags: c++

I am really hoping that you all can help me with this problem. I am both new to the site and new to C++ (only been learning for about a month). My compiler is VS2012. I am working on a set of menus for a program. The menus use simple switch statements for each of their classes. Each menu is derived from a base menu class. Since I do not seem to be having any issues with the menu classes themselves, I am not including them at the moment since they are all in separate .cpp files with their own .h header files. I am including the base menu .cpp and .h files since I believe they are part of my issue. I am also including my main .cpp file.

BaseMenu.h

```
    #ifndef BaseMenu_M
    #define BaseMenu_M


    #include<string>
    #include<iostream>



    using std::cout;


    class BaseMenu
    {
    public:

        BaseMenu() { m_MenuText = "This is where the menu text choices will appear"; }// Constructor providing menu text to each derived menu
        virtual ~BaseMenu() { }             // virtual destructor
        virtual BaseMenu getNextMenu(int iChoice, bool& iIsQuitOptionSelected);         // used to set up the framework
        virtual void printText()                                                                    // member function to display the menu text
        {
            cout << m_MenuText << std::endl;
        }

    protected:
        std::string m_MenuText;     // string will be shared by all derived classes
    };

    #endif
```

BaseMenu.cpp

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "BaseMenu.h"
    #include<iostream>


    BaseMenu::BaseMenu(void)
    {
    }


    BaseMenu::~BaseMenu(void)
    {
    }
```

Main .cpp file

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "BaseMenu.h"
    #include "TicketSalesMenu.h"
    #include "MainMenu.h"
    #include "ListMenu.h"
    #include "AdministrativeTasksMenu.h"
    #include "basemenu.h"


    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using std::cin;



    int tmain (int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {


        BaseMenu* aCurrentMenu = new MainMenu;          // Pointer to the current working menu

        bool isQuitOptionSelected = false;
        while (!isQuitOptionSelected)                   // set to keep menus running until the quit option is selected
        {

            aCurrentMenu->printText();                  // call and print the menu text for the currently active menu

            int choice = 0;                             // Initializing choice variable and setting it to 0
            cin >> choice;

            BaseMenu* aNewMenuPointer = aCurrentMenu->getNextMenu(choice, isQuitOptionSelected); // This will return a new object, of the type of the new menu we want. Also checks if quit was selected //**This is the line that the error is reported**//

            if (aNewMenuPointer) 
            {
                delete aCurrentMenu;                    // clean up the old menu
        aCurrentMenu = aNewMenuPointer;                 // updating the 'current menu' with the new menu
            }
        }

        return true;    
    }
```

For some reason I can not figure out, I am receiving a

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'BaseMenu' to 'BaseMenu*'. This error is in the main .cpp file on line 35, which is

```
    "BaseMenu* aNewMenuPointer = aCurrentMenu->getNextMenu(choice, isQuitOptionSelected);"
```

I have looked at multiple similar questions from this site and others. One of the solutions I tried, resulted in multiple link errors for all my menu classes. It has taken me 3 days to get the errors reduced to just this one remaining error and I am at a loss.

Comment: `BaseMenu::getNextMenu` is declared to return an *instance* of a `BaseMenu`, but `aNewMenuPointer` is a *pointer* to a `BaseMenu`. A value and a pointer to a value are two very different things.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you the problem. `getNextMenu` returns an actual `BaseMenu` object, but you are trying to assign it to a pointer to a `BaseMenu` object.